# Subquery a Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, subquery, case

STEP 1:

I have the following code which produces the table below:

```
USE EMTCQIData

SELECT * , (FCT_MAX_CHARGES - CPT_CHARGES) AS DELTA
FROM
    (
    SELECT CONC.[FIN] as FIN, CONC.Clinical, 
        CASE
          WHEN CONC.Clinical like '%level 5%' THEN '9285' 
        END FCT_MAX,
        CASE
          WHEN CONC.Clinical like '%level 5%' THEN CAST($200 AS int) 
        END FCT_MAX_CHARGES,
        CPT.CPT,
        CASE
          WHEN CPT.CPT like '9285' THEN CAST($200 AS int) 
        END CPT_CHARGES
    FROM CPT_MASTER as CPT
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ST2.[FIN], 
            SUBSTRING(
              (
                SELECT ','+ST1.[Clinical Event Result]  AS [text()]
                FROM ED_FCT_Q1_FY19 ST1
                WHERE ST1.[FIN] = ST2.[Financial Number] AND ST1.[FIN]<> 'No'
                Order BY [Financial Number] 
                FOR XML PATH ('')
              ), 2, 1000) [Clinical]
        FROM ED_FCT_Q1_FY19 ST2
    ) as CONC ON CONC.[Financial Number]=CPT.FIN
    WHERE CPT.CPT LIKE '9928%'
) AS COMPLETE
ORDER BY FIN
```

PRODUCED TABLE (results table 1)

```
FIN   Clinical                           FCT_MAX   FCT_MAX_Charges    CPT  CPT_Charges  DELTA 
1     Dicharge[Level2] Transfer [Level3]  9284       200             9283    100        100
```

STEP 2:

I have a CASE code that parses out the Clinical column based on Level of clinical event(without any of the CPT/FCT data because its not in the ED_FCT_Q1_FY19 table). So for example, the produced results above will look the same except that the Clinical column will be replaced by individual level columns.

How can I nest this CASE code within the code from above to produce the desired table below.

DESIRED TABLE

```
FIN   Level 1  Level 3             FCT_MAX   FCT_MAX_Charges    CPT  CPT_Charges  DELTA 
1     Dicharge Transfer            9284       200             9283    100        100
```

Example of the Case code I used to parse out the CLINICAL COLUMN from results table 1

```
SELECT [Financial Number], [Clinical Event Result],

CASE
   WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%1:1 Nursing care%' Then '1'
      ELSE '0'
End [1:1 Nursing Care],

CASE
   WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Admission or O.R. preparation%' Then '1'
      ELSE '0'
End [Admission or O.R. preparation],
FROM ED_FCT_Q1_FY19
```

Comment: just off the top of my head, i would say that you might want to look into Cross Apply/Outer Apply.. this would go after `inner join() as CONC` and would be able to use the result of `CONC`

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @Shawn, I'm suing SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: @JamieD77, thanks!

Comment: Right, but what version of SQL? You can run `SELECT @@version`.

Comment: @Shawn, it's 2012 SP3